# SQL - failed criteria with multiple <>

Tags: sql, postgresql

It's probably something very basic I'm missing. This is the scenario:

#### TABLE

- t1

#### COLUMNS:

- id (UUID)
- id_e (UUID)
- category (VARCHAR)

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM t1

| count |
|-------|
| 700000|
```

When a search for an specific row it return zero rows

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM t1
WHERE id = '7ea67ae0-aef8-4944-bfb4-b9e04b42143a'::UUID
AND id_e = 'fa9763f5-c9e0-4de3-be57-ab3149fb1b9f'::UUID
AND category = 'A+'

| count |
|-------|
|      0|
```

When a search for any row that doesn't match the same criteria it returns less rows than the first query

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM t1
WHERE id <> '7ea67ae0-aef8-4944-bfb4-b9e04b42143a'::UUID
AND id_e <> 'fa9763f5-c9e0-4de3-be57-ab3149fb1b9f'::UUID
AND category <> 'A+'

| count |
|-------|
| 385221|
```

What is wrong with this criteria? It seems it is behaving like `OR` instead or `AND`

Comment: Boolean logic: `not(A and B) = not(A) ` **`or`** `not(B)`…

Comment: When you invert a logical expression, you need to change the `=` to `<>` and all of the `AND`s to `OR`s. So `WHERE id = '7ea67ae0-aef8-4944-bfb4-b9e04b42143a'::UUID
AND id_e = 'fa9763f5-c9e0-4de3-be57-ab3149fb1b9f'::UUID
AND category = 'A+'` would become `WHERE id <> '7ea67ae0-aef8-4944-bfb4-b9e04b42143a'::UUID
OR id_e <> 'fa9763f5-c9e0-4de3-be57-ab3149fb1b9f'::UUID
OR category <> 'A+'`

Comment: Also consider the case all rows have category 'A+', but none of the id's match.

Comment: And also consider the possibility of `null` values in these columns... in which case `is [not] distinct from` (null-safe equality) would be more appropriate that `=` and `<>`.

Comment: Change `AND` to `OR` in the second query. Is any of those columns nullable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your criteria of

```
id = '7ea67ae0-aef8-4944-bfb4-b9e04b42143a'::UUID
AND id_e = 'fa9763f5-c9e0-4de3-be57-ab3149fb1b9f'::UUID
AND category = 'A+'
```

can be negated as

```
NOT
(
id = '7ea67ae0-aef8-4944-bfb4-b9e04b42143a'::UUID
AND id_e = 'fa9763f5-c9e0-4de3-be57-ab3149fb1b9f'::UUID
AND category = 'A+'
)
```

## De Morgan's laws

[image]

Proof

A B NOT(A OR B) (NOT A) AND (NOT B):

I. A = 0, B = 0:

- NOT(A OR B) = 1
- (NOT A) AND (NOT B) = 1

II. A = 0, B = 1:

- NOT(A OR B) = 0
- (NOT A) AND (NOT B) = 0

III. A = 1, B = 0:

- NOT(A OR B) = 0
- (NOT A) AND (NOT B) = 0

IV. A = 1, B = 1:

- NOT(A OR B) = 0
- (NOT A) AND (NOT B) = 0

## Composite case

Let's suppose that

A = A1 and A2

and we are to compute

NOT (A AND B).

So:

NOT (A AND B) =

(NOT A) OR (NOT B) =

(NOT (A1 AND A2)) OR (NOT B) =

((NOT A1) OR (NOT A2)) OR (NOT B) =

(NOT A1) OR (NOT A2) OR (NOT B)

therefore

NOT (A AND B AND C) = (NOT A) OR (NOT B) OR (NOT C)

Therefore

```
NOT
(
id = '7ea67ae0-aef8-4944-bfb4-b9e04b42143a'::UUID
AND id_e = 'fa9763f5-c9e0-4de3-be57-ab3149fb1b9f'::UUID
AND category = 'A+'
)
```

is equivalent with:

```
(
(NOT id = '7ea67ae0-aef8-4944-bfb4-b9e04b42143a'::UUID)
OR (NOT id_e = 'fa9763f5-c9e0-4de3-be57-ab3149fb1b9f'::UUID)
OR (NOT category = 'A+')
)
```

## What your mistake was

You wanted to negate A AND B AND C, but you did (NOT A) AND (NOT B) AND (NOT C). Now, let's consider the case when A is false, but B and C are true. In this case both A AND B AND C and (NOT A) AND (NOT B) AND (NOT C) will be false, hence, they are clearly not a negation of each-other.